# MySQL syntax error within PHP app, though works in MySQL terminal

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post, putty

**EDIT: 'solution' in my comment below**

I am doing an AJAX POST to my back-end PHP where form data gets sent to a dedicated CRUD php form and is used to create a record.

The SQL syntax is such that I need 2 commands.  Therefore, I use a `BEGIN TRANSACTION; statements; COMMIT;` structure, thus:

```
START TRANSACTION; 
INSERT INTO tblTask (subject, dateOpened, priority) VALUES 
    ('test 1', '2017-02-22 07:09:33', 3); 
INSERT INTO tblTaskContent (idTask, dateEntered, text) VALUES 
    (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '2017-02-22 07:09:33', 'fdsa'); 
COMMIT;
```

*formatted for clarity, though all statements separated by ; and a following space.

That MySQL statement is spat out to the web console via a PHP echo statement, so that's what the program is outputting verbatim.

Here's the PHP:

```
if($action == 1)     //CREATE
{
    if($taskVarArr['subject'] && $taskVarArr['priority'] && $taskVarArr['content']) //can create the initial record
    {
        if(ReadTask($taskVarArr)) //task exists, consider updating existing record
        {
            echo "Row exists!"; //TODO IS DEBUG
            return http_response_code(400);
            die();
        }
        else if(CreateTask($taskVarArr)) //new record, insert
        {
            return http_response_code(200);
            die();
        }
    }

    //if this reached, bad request
    return http_response_code(400);
    die();
}
elseif($action == 2) //READ ...not used yet
{

}
```

EDIT: Here are the PHP functions CreateTask and ReadTask:

```
// Create - CRUD
function CreateTask($taskVarArr) //sorry for your eyes
{
    $conn = OpenConnection();
    $workingDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

    $sql = "START TRANSACTION; ";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO tblTask (subject, dateOpened, priority) VALUES ".
        "('".$taskVarArr['subject']."', '$workingDate', ".$taskVarArr['priority']."); "; //TODO below this breaks
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO tblTaskContent (idTask, dateEntered, text) VALUES ".
        "(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$workingDate', '".$taskVarArr['content']."'); "; //LAST_INSERT_ID() grabs last autonumber
    $sql .= "COMMIT;";

    //TODO IS DEBUG
    echo $sql;
    //TODO IS DEBUG

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($result)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// Read - CRUD; Only checks if record exists
function ReadTask($taskVarArr)
{
    $conn = OpenConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT idTask from tblTask WHERE subject = '".$taskVarArr['subject']."';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['idTask'];
    }

    return false;
}
```

I get a 400 error on creation since ReadTask doesn't find the record and CreateTask doesn't complete successfully.  However, when I paste the same statement into my MySQL PuTTY window without additional formatting, it accepts it just fine.  After trying to run again with the same information, the program detects the row(s) exist and echoes "Row exists!" as it's supposed to.  I have verified all credentials are correct and the connection is being opened as expected.

Is `LAST_INSERT_ID()` limited to PDO or a specific implementation within PHP?  I thought MySQL was meant to interpret that.

If you're curious, I've split up tblTask and its content in tblTaskContent because I want the user to be able to add updates to their task as they go along.  There's a tblTask id FK and a timestamp in tblTaskContent to keep the data linked and sortable based on update entry time.

Comment: As far as I know is that PHP can't have stacked query strings

Comment: `$sql = "START TRANSACTION; ";` isn't your db connection that suppose to start a Transaction ? to be like $con->ST.....`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

```
// Create - CRUD
function CreateTask($taskVarArr) //sorry for your eyes
{
    $conn = OpenConnection();
    $workingDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblTask (subject, dateOpened, priority) VALUES ".
        "('".$taskVarArr['subject']."', '$workingDate', ".$taskVarArr['priority']."); ";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tblTaskContent (idTask, dateEntered, text) VALUES ".
            "(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$workingDate', '".$taskVarArr['content']."'); "; //LAST_INSERT_ID() grabs last autonumber
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

That's a dumb solution.  I was hoping utilizing both mysqli_autocommit and mysqli_commit after the mysqli_querys would work, but it don't.  It seems if I want a transaction I'll have to (learn how to) use PDO.